# Interfaces in cpp

Tags: c++, interface

As you will soon see, I am not a c++ developer and for this problem I am working on c++ is my only option.  I don't mind learning, so just some guidance would be appreciated.

I have a panel class as follows:

```
class Panel {
    ...  // Methods that implement Panel
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    ...  // Other methods to implement Panel
}
```

And I want two varieties of it so I create two interfaces

```
class Foo {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class Bar: public Foo {
    virtual void bar() = 0;
}
```

I want to pass the implementing class of Foo to other classes and have them only be able to call the method foo, and the same for Bar.

In other languages I could create the class that implements Foo as:

```
class FooPanel : public Panel,  implements Foo{ ... }
```

or

```
class BarPanel : public Panel, implments Bar { ... }
```

then I can pass into a method:

```
//method(..., foo* pFoo, ...);  the signature
  method(..., (Foo*)&barPanel, ...);
```

The only way I can see to accomplish this in c++ is to:

```
class FooPanel : public Panel {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}
```

then one has to pass the entire Panel and the implementer is capable of calling and Panel method.

Where can I look to get an idea of how this can be done?

Comment: I don't understand what's stopping you from deriving from both classes? Are you unaware of multiple inheritance?

Comment: C++, for good and ill, supports multiple inheritance. That one or all of the base classes is an abstract, pure virtual, class is unimportant..

Comment: Think of it as java's default implementations in its interfaces. Just replace `implements` with `public`.

Comment: Handy reading: [Inheritance — Multiple and Virtual Inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance)

Comment: Sorry, living in the dark ages.

Comment: @Nefarious I'm not sure exactly what you are after so I'm not sure if I should make an answer. I just made an example instead. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/4Y8G86nWd). Is that what you want?

Comment: Don't inherit publicly if you don't want the public `Panel` functions publicly available.

Comment: Or use composition instead of inheritance. But like others have stated, there's not quite enough information to fully understand what the end-goal is and how the pieces are intended to interact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What other languages (such as java) call "interfaces" is just an abstract base class in C++.  So if you just replace the `implements` keyword with `public virtual`, it will work as you expect:

```
class FooPanel : public Panel, public virtual Foo { ... }

class BarPanel : public Panel, public virtual Bar { ... }
```

Comment: I believe this still creates the issue of the `Panel` functions being visible in `FooPanel`, which OP doesn't want. The better solution might be composition, where a `Panel` is a private member.

Comment: @sweenish: The `Panel` functions are not visible in `Foo`, which is what the OP says they want.  Their java example has the `Panel` functions similarly visible in `FooPanel` which makes perfect sense.

Comment: Chalk it up to my no-knowledge of Java, then.

Comment: yes, this is correct, holders of pointers to Foo can only call foo.  Works as asked.  One must be very careful with multiple inheritance.  As long as the second, ... levels are pure virtual, it is straight forward.  Thanks this made all of the difference.